# Data Structure for choosing a Task having Max Reward and requiring Min amount of Time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

Small question regarding a *Data structure* which would allow to choose a *Task* having the *maximum rewards* and with the *minimum amount of time* (when *rewards* of several *tasks* are equal).

Considering a case when I have the following Tasks:

- Task Alice, will earn me `500`, I need to spend `10` hours.
- Task Bob, will earn me `2000`, I need to spend `3` hours.
- Task Charlie, will earn me `100`, I need to spend `1` hour.
- Task David, will earn me `1000`, I need to spend `20` hours.
- Task Elsa, will earn me `1200`, I need to spend `60` hours.
- Task Franck, will earn me `400`, I need to spend `5` hours.
- Task Grace, will earn me `400`, I need to spend `6` hours.

Is it possible to get a data structure which will have this result:

```
2000 | 3
1200 | 60
1000 | 20
 500 | 10
 400 | 5
 400 | 6
 100 | 1
```

Explanation:

***Note:*** I can't retake a task once it is done.

As you can see with tasks Franck and Grace, which both earn 400, for respectively 5 hours of work and 6 hours of work. 400 | 5 comes first, because if I could only do one job out of the two (earn 400) I would chose task F, since it will take me less to earn the same.

Now between task David 1000 | 20 and Elsa, 1200 | 60, even if task D earn technically 50 per hour, and task E only earn 20 per hour, I would still chose task E 1200 | 60, because if I could take only one job out of the two, I will chose to earn 1200 instead of 1000.

My question: what is the best data structure in Java to represent this please?

*I've tried:*

- `HashMap`:

Unfortunately, `HashMap` isn't sorted, and in order to decide which jobs to take, I need to build one for loop to find the maximum, and if I find multiple, to loop again on the values to get the minimum.

- Two `PriorityQueue`s.

While one queue will order properly the earning, and one will order properly the hours, I will end up with

```
Q1 = [2000, 1200, 1000, 500, 400, 400, 100]
Q2 = `[1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 20, 60]
```

I lose all relationship and "mapping" between the two, making searches ineffective.

What would be the best way to find a Task with the *max reward* and the *min of amount of time* (for *tasks* with equal *rewards*)?

P.S. From the comments, it seems this looks like a leetcode question or homework, but it is not, I am just trying to find what is the best data structure to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can you show what code you've written so far? Have you looked into the knapsack porblem? Seems similar

Comment: Use one priority queue on a `Comparator.comparing(t -> -t.rewards).thenComparing(t -> t.hours)`

Comment: You're just sorting on two fields: first reward, then, if rewards are equal, on hours. Data structures are for a particular use. You only talk about "holding" so you should use a list and sort it once.

Comment: What you're asking (sorting by most benefit for least effort) and the example you've given (sort by reward, descending, then by effort, ascending) are incongruous. Either way, it sounds like you want a list of objects whose comparator works one of those two ways. Nothing about your problem indicates that a specialized data structure is required.

Comment: "The maximum reward with the minimum of effort" is ambiguous, because you can maximize only one of these at a time. Made most clear by this sentence: "because if I could take only one job out of the two, I will chose to earn 1200 instead of 1000." If the only constraint is the number of jobs you can take, you want the ones that earns the most, regardless of how long they take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the Power of Objects

Firstly, you need an object `Task`, attempts to maintain values of *rewards* and *hours* separately are error-prone and not viable.

Irregardless of this particular problem, it's not justifiable to store separately values which make sense only as a whole. They should constitute an object.

Hence, you need to create a `class`, or a Java 16 [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html). I'll go with the latter, because this option far is more concise.

```
public record Task(String createdBy, int reward, int hours) {}
```

## Choosing a Data structure

Now, let's get back to the actual problem.

We need a data structure which would allow to consume these *tasks* in sorted order. For that purpose, we can use either a [*Red-black tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (represented with a `TreeSet` class in the JDK), or a [*Heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) (represented with a `PriorityQueue` class in the JDK).

From the performance perspective, maintaining a *Heap* is less constful than maintaining a *Red-black tree*.

And using a *Heap* also fits very well in the nature of *tasks*. Once a *task* is consumed it can't be useful anymore, hence there's no need to store it. And with a *Max-Heap* (a *Heap* where all elements are lower or equal to the *root-element*) to access the maximum element we need to have a look at its *root*. And in order to find the next maximum element we need to remove the current *root*.

Hence, [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#method-summary) would be an optimal choice.

## Implementation

While instantiating `PriorityQueue` to make it capable to dial with our objects, they either need to implement `Comparable` interface, or we need to provide a `Comparator`.

I'll go with the second option because I don't feel `Task` has a *natural order* (the only sorted order which make sense for the object), because we might want to sort them differently.

Since Java 8 the recommended way to implement a `Comparator` is by using [static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#method-summary) of this interface. Each of these methods like `comparing()` and `comparingInt()` returns a `Comparator` and we can chain them in a fluent way in order to create a *comparator* based on the multiple conditions.

Here's how it can be implemented using `PriorityQueue`:

```
Queue<Task> tasks = new PriorityQueue<>(
    Comparator.comparingInt(Task::reward)                      // the first sorting criterion - Reward
        .thenComparing(Task::hours, Comparator.reverseOrder()) // the second sorting criterion - Hours in Reversed Order
        .reversed()                                            // we need the whole thing in Descending order - from Max to Min
);
        
Collections.addAll(tasks,
    new Task("Alice", 500, 10),
    new Task("Bob", 2000, 3),
    new Task("Charlie", 100, 1),
    new Task("David", 1000, 20),
    new Task("Elsa", 1200, 60),
    new Task("Franck", 400, 5),
    new Task("Grace", 400, 6)
);
        
while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
    // your Logic for consuming a Task goes here:
    Task next = tasks.remove();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Task[createdBy=Bob, reward=2000, hours=3]
Task[createdBy=Elsa, reward=1200, hours=60]
Task[createdBy=David, reward=1000, hours=20]
Task[createdBy=Alice, reward=500, hours=10]
Task[createdBy=Franck, reward=400, hours=5]
Task[createdBy=Grace, reward=400, hours=6]
Task[createdBy=Charlie, reward=100, hours=1]
```

Comment: Very detailed answer @Alexander, thank you